# Why should I put the source file name before library names on compiler command line?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, opensuse, gcc

As a user of OpenSUSE I am used to type:

```
gcc -lz myfile.c
```

I was surprised that on Ubuntu this command would fail with something like:

```
myfile.c:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `zlibVersion'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

With `gcc -v` I found that the `collect2` command generated by the GCC C compiler on Ubuntu starts with `--as-needed` while on OpenSUSE this option is not there. I.e. the command line on Ubuntu looks like:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr\
-m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker \
....[a lot of stuff removed].....\
-lz /tmp/cc7kz9Nz.o ....[yet more stuff removed].....\
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

While on OpenSUSE it looks quite similar but for the `--as-needed` option.

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/collect2 --build-id --eh-frame-hdr\
-m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker \
....[a lot of stuff removed].....\
-lz /tmp/cccpZlmL.o ....[yet more stuff removed].....\
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

Where did this difference come from? Has it been discussed somewhere? Should I never put library names before the source file name?

Comment: I am surprised this works on OpenSUSE. Order of compiler arguments matters a lot on Unix since the 1980s.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch this specific thing works both on RedHat and SuSE and derivatieves the switch was made by Debian in around 2011 as you can read following the link given by Stephen Kitt. Though the order of `-l` options still matters on these systems.

Comment: And most importantly, that order matters elsewhere (on other Unix or Posix systems, and probably on non-Posix or non-Unix ones). So keeping the habit to care about order of arguments to `gcc` (and indirectly to `ld`) is a good thing. I believe that teaching to care about order of arguments to `gcc` is essential, and expecting `gcc -lz myfile.c` to work is a bad habit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented [on the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ToolChain/CompilerFlags#A-Wl.2C--as-needed). It’s set by default to reduce the number of dependencies in packages, but as you discovered it means the order of libraries is significant: you need to ensure that objects (of any type) appear *before* the libraries they use.

You can disable this with `--no-as-needed`.